# H is an abelian proper subgroup of G with $H \cap gHg^{−1} = \{e\}$ for all $ g \notin H $ then $H$ is equal to centralizer of $H$ in $G$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group with identity $e$. Let H be an abelian non-trivial proper subgroup of G with
the property that $H \cap gHg^{−1} =  \{e\}$ for all $ g \notin H $. If $K = \{ g \in G : gh = hg \, \, \,    \forall h \in H\}$. I want to prove the following. $$ \\ (1) H = K \\  (2) \text {there exists no abelian subgroup $L$ $\subset$ G such that $K$ is a proper subgroup of $L$ } $$. I tried the following . To prove part $(1)$ it is trivial to see that $ H \subset K $ as $H$ is an abelain group. Now we have to show that $ K \subset H $ for this let $ x \in K \implies xh = hx \, \,  \forall h \in H \, \, so \, \,  xHx^{-1} = H $. I got stuck here how to proceed further. To prove part $(2)$ i tried way of contradiction suppose there exist an abelian subgroup $L$ of $G$ such that K is a proper subgroup of $L$ . Then there exist $x \in K \text {such that} x \notin L $ so $x$ commute with all elements of $ H$ . Now how to proceed further. Thank you for help.

Comment: Hint: If $g$ centralizes $H$, what is $gHg^{-1}$?

Comment: it is $H$. i reached here

Comment: Right, so if some element outside $H$ centralizes $H$, what happens?

Comment: in this case $ H \cap g H g ^{-1} \text { is not equal to identity} $. thank you

Comment: how to proceed part 2

Comment: Part 2 follows immediately from part 1.

Comment: it's very trivial to see. i should change my way of understanding mathematics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, $H\subseteq K$. Suppose $H\subsetneq K$. Then there is a $k\in K\setminus H$. Since $k\notin H$, we have $H\cap kHk^{-1}=\{e\}$. Now, choose $h(\neq e)\in H$(possible because $H$ is non-trivial). Then $khk^{-1}=h\in H\cap kHk^{-1}=\{e\},$ a contradiction.